# Specifying the probability space: Drawing numbered cards without replacement

Tags: probability

Consider a hat with $7$ numbered  cards $(1,..,7)$. If you draw $4$ cards without replacement and arrange them into a four digit number (card drawn first is the first digit and so on...) what is the probability space ($\Omega, \mathcal F,P)?$

We just started learning about probability spaces and I am a bit confused:

1. As far as I understand, $\Omega $ presents the set of all possible outcomes. Would my outcomes in this case be $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ since this includes all the numbered cards that I can draw or would $\Omega$ be the set of all possible four digit numbers that I could make? How could I even write this down in compact set notation?
2. For the event space I was thinking that this could be $2^{\Omega}$. Is the event space always the set of all subsets of $\Omega$? For example, would in this case $\{1,2\}$ be in $\mathcal F$ even though in the question I am only looking for four digit numbers?
3. $P$ has been the hardest for me to understand. In simpler cases it was just $P(A)=\frac{\lvert A \rvert}{\lvert \Omega\rvert}$. However, this kind of probability function doesn't really make any sense. How can I construct a function in this case and is there an "easy" way to construct this function in general?

Comment: I would say that $\Omega$ is the set of all four digit numbers comprised of those seven digits without repeats.  Thus $\Omega=\{1234,1235,1236,1237,1245, \cdots\}$.

Comment: Abstractly, $\Omega$ is the set of ordered subsets of size $4$ of that list.  It has $7\times 6\times 5\times 4$ elements.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the response! Yes that makes sense. Is there some compact way I can write $\Omega$? Would $\mathcal F$ still be $2^{\Omega}$ then?

Comment: Not a terribly clear one.  Might be easier to work with base $7$ numbers, as those can all be expressend with $7$ digits.  But I doubt that helps.